# Hostname Can't be null

Tags: java, wildfly

I am receiving  an error when I try to access our java application.  When I start wildfly 18 it works find.  However when I try to access the web site it throughs an error.  Currently wildfly is on a windows machine.  This is the error stack.  I had to copy it so they may be some typos.  When I look through the start up it shows the server name correctly.  Han help is appreciated.

```
2021-02-07 21:52:02,319 ERROR[io.undertow.request] (default yask-1 UT005023: Exception handeling request to /eemt: javax.servlet.ServletException:UT010013: Could not instantiate UserAuthenticationFilter
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.MangedFilter.createFilter(ManagedFilter.java:77)
    at io.undetwo.servlet.core,ManagedFilter.forceInit(ManagedFilter.java:125)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.Servletchain.forceInit(ServletChain.java:126
    at.io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:126)
    at.io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletCHain$1.hanlerequest(ServletChain.java:63)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociatioHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContectAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handler.PredicatHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.understow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLinformationAssociationHandlre.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallhandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(predicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstrainHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechaniismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSEssionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.secuirty.handlers.NotificationReceievedhandler.handleRequest(NotificationReciverHandler.java.50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSEcurityContextAssoicationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(Preducatehandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIDHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIDHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(Predicatehandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllhandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)

    at org.wildfly.extention.undertow.security.securityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.securitycontextThreadSetupAction$$Lambda$1022/992251130.call(unknown Source)
    at org.wilfly.extension.undertow.deployment.undertowdevelopmentinfoservice$undertowthreadsetupaction.lambda$create$0(undertowdeploymentinfoservice.java:1502
    at org.wilfly.extension.undertow.deployment.undertowdevelopmentinfoservice$undertowthreadsetupaction$$lambda$1023/875004270.call(unknown source)
    at org.wilfly.extension.undertow.deployment.undertowdevelopmentinfoservice$undertowthreadsetupaction.lambda$create$0(undertowdeploymentinfoservice.java:1502
    at org.wilfly.extension.undertow.deployment.undertowdevelopmentinfoservice$undertowthreadsetupaction$$lambda$1023/875004270.call(unknown source)
    at org.wilfly.extension.undertow.deployment.undertowdevelopmentinfoservice$undertowthreadsetupaction.lambda$create$0(undertowdeploymentinfoservice.java:1502
    at org.wilfly.extension.undertow.deployment.undertowdevelopmentinfoservice$undertowthreadsetupaction$$lambda$1023/875004270.call(unknown source)
    at org.wilfly.extension.undertow.deployment.undertowdevelopmentinfoservice$undertowthreadsetupaction.lambda$create$0(undertowdeploymentinfoservice.java:1502
    at org.wilfly.extension.undertow.deployment.undertowdevelopmentinfoservice$undertowthreadsetupaction$$lambda$1023/875004270.call(unknown source)

Caused by: java.lang.illegalstateexception: WFLYEE0042: Failed to contstruct component instance
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentinstance(BasicComponent.java:163)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentinstance(BasicComponent.java:133)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.basiccomponet,creatinstance(basiccomponet.java:88)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.compoent.componentregistry$component,amahedreferencefactory.getreference(componetregistry,java:149)
    at org.wildfly.extensiom.undertpw.deployment.undertowdeploymentinfoservice$6.createinstance(undertowdepoloymentinfor service.java:1215)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.managedfilter.createfilter(managedfilter.java:75)

Caused by: java.lang.illegalargumentexception: hostname cant be null
    at java.net inetsocketaddress.checkhost(inetsocketaddress.java:149)
    at java.net.inetsocketaddress.<init>(inetsocketaddress.java:216)
    at commons.cache.memcachedImpl.<init>(MemcachedImpl.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newinstance0(native method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newinstance(nativeconstructoraccessorimpl.java.62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(delegatingConstructorAccessorImp.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.newInstance(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:119)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.ConstructorInjectionPoint.invokeAroundConstructCallbacks(ConstructorInjectionPoint.java:92)
```

Comment: I can't see the stack trace.

Comment: I am tying to add it.  it keeps saying that its not properly formated and wont let me post it

Comment: Try to put it between \`\`\` tags.

Comment: can you see it in the post?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking into that

Comment: `MemcachedImpl.java` is yours?

Comment: It looks like you've got a servlet filter that attempts to create a socket. You'll want to look at `commons.cache.memcachedImpl.<init>(MemcachedImpl.java:78)`.

Comment: I moved wildfly to a new host and now i am getting this error.  It works just fine on the other host.  That host is running docker but i didnt think it should mater.

Comment: I appreciate the help